# Нужна ли запятая после слова "быстрее"?

Tags: запятые

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая после слова "быстрее" и почему? Никак не получается найти правило для этого случая.

> Он вернулся к себе домой. Быстрее, туда!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Он вернулся к себе домой. **Быстрее туда!***

***Быстрее*** и ***туда*** — неоднородные обстоятельства (образа действия и места), при прочтении без паузы разделения запятой не требуют.

Но при интонационном разделении слов ***быстрее*** и ***туда*** паузу нужно как-то обозначить.

Возможные варианты:

*Он вернулся к себе домой. **Быстрее, туда!***

*Он вернулся к себе домой. **Быстрее! Туда!***